# Пользователи SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Скажем у меня есть две таблицы: **1.Организация**; **2.Сотрудник**.(1коМногим). У меня есть хранимка, которая возвращает сотрудников организации. Приложение на asp net mvc, в системе может быть две разные организации, как между ними ограничивают доступ к данным? Ну скажем если зашла организация А в свой аккаунт, то ей должны будут доступны только свои сотрудники. Я знаю, что есть пользователи на sqlServer, но не знаю конкретно можно ли там как-то разграничивать доступ. Ну и плюс ко всему чтобы работало с asp.net пользователями. Вроде слышал, что нужно к пользователям хранимки привязывать, но это не точно.

Answer (score 1):

У каждого зарегистрированного на сайте пользователя есть в БД свой уникальный идентификатор.
То, что вы хотите, можно реализовать несколькими способами

1 Способ:
Создать (у вас уже есть) таблицу организаций

```
ID | OrganizationName
1  | First Organization
2  | Second Organization
```

И создать промежуточную таблицу. В ней происходит объединение уникального идентификатора пользователя и уникального идентификатора компании

```
UserID | OrganizationID
1      | 1
2      | 1
3      | 2
```

Этот способ хорош в том случае, если один пользователь может составлять сразу в нескольких компаниях (например, главный администратор сайта).

Этот способ можно реализовать за счёт уже встроенных таблиц roles и userroles, которые создаются в бд. Вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам достаточно просто заменить имена ролей на названия организаций

Проверку на роль тогда можно будет выполнять командой

```
  if (Context.User.IsInRole("Administrator") || Context.User.IsInRole("Manager"))
  { 
     Создаём отображение страницы для указанных ролей 
  }
  else
  {
     Создаём для остальных
  }
```

2 Способ:

Будет работать, если у каждого пользователя может быть только одна уникальная компания

Для этого достаточно создать новый столбец в таблице пользователей, который будет содержать идентификатор организации.

Тогда мы просто будем выгружать из БД информацию о пользователях на серверной части сайта и обрабатывать её по средствам проверок.

Надеюсь, я правильно понял ваш вопрос!

ОБНОВЛЕНО!!!!

Таблица пользователей:

```
ID  | UserName(Organization)
521 | Organization1
522 | Organization2
```

Таблица сотрудников:

```
ID  | FirstName | LastName
97  | Ivan      | Ivanov
98  | Sergey    | Sergeev
99  | Вася      | Пупкин
100 | Пётр      | Иванович
```

Таблица связей:

```
IDUser | IDCo-worker
521    | 97
522    | 98
521    | 99
522    | 100
```

Логика кода

```
//Получить ID авторизованного пользователя
//SQL запрос на получение из таблицы связей строк IDCo-worker, IDUser в которых соответствует ID авторизованного пользователя.
Пример запроса для MySQL (для SQL придётся смотреть самому): **SELECT IDCo-worker FROM Имя_таблицы_связей WHERE IDUser='ID_авторизованного_пользователя'**
//На выходе получим все IDCo-worker, которые имеют связь с ID авторизованного пользователя (в данным случае, есть 2 организации в которых по 2 сотрудника).
//Далее делаем аналогичный запрос в БД сотрудников но уже в цикле, так как у нас несколько сотрудников
for(int i = 0; i<длины_строк_подходящих_под_предыдущий_запрос_в_БД; i++)
{
**SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Имя_таблицы_сотрудников WHERE ID='IDCo-worker[i]'**
Выводим имя и фамилию на экран!
}
```

Примерно такую логику нужно организовать в коде. Если будут вопросы, пишите. Единственное отличие - я работаю с MySQL.

Comment: Например если у меня 100 пользователей, которым соответствует 100 организаций в базе и соответственно свои сотрудники, то мне нужно будет делать 100 проверок для вывода ? (if). Я правильно понял? В зависимости от  пользователя авторизовавшегося в системе

Comment: Видимо, я не совсем  понял ваш вопрос. Получается, что на сайте авторизуется пользователь, который является представителем организации и ему необходимо получить всех сотрудников, которые относятся к его организации. Если так, то у вас получается 3 таблицы: Пользователи (организации), сотрудники организации и таблица связей между пользователями и организациями. Тогда, в программе мы получаем ID авторизованного пользователя. После этого обращаемся по средствам SQL запроса к таблице связей и ищем там все ID сотрудников, которым соответствует ID пользователя.

Comment: Найдя первое совпадение вы обращается с уже известным ID сотрудника к таблице сотрудников и проверяем каждую строку на совпадения ID сотрудника. Как только совпало, останавливаем поиск и возвращаемся к таблице соотношений и продолжаем поиск совпадений далее. Так до конца

Comment: Второй раз вы правильно поняли. Получается всё сводится к тому, что в хранимой процедуре выбора сотрудников мне нужно добавить поиск по id авторизованного пользователя(организации)? Я изначально думал о таком варианте, но посчитал, что возможен какой-то более лучший вариант. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Обновил сообщение. Теперь внизу есть описание той логики, которой вам необходимо придерживаться. Если не получиться реализовать - обращайтесь. У меня есть рабочие примеры функционала, который вам нужен (на MySQL запросах).